# Class, interface, or enum expected when compiling

Tags: java, bluej

I sat down and tried to write code for [this prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phDFE.jpg), and I made [this](http://pastebin.com/2cJiQAYJ).
However, when I compile it in BlueJ, I get: **class, interface, or enum expected**.

1) How do I fix this error? It seems like I forgot something, but I cant remember what I forgot.

2) Do you think I fulfilled what the prompt was asking?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to put your method inside a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do your homework for you but here are some hints:

1. You need to put all your code inside a **class**
2. You need to put the code in the **main method**. (Search on Google) the method served for an entry point.
3. You only need one for loop... Loop through the array, if the value equals 0, return the index number. After the loop just return -1.